# django clear form field after a submit

Tags: python, django, forms

I have an upload form,After every form submit,i want to clear the posted data,actually the form is holding the submitted data.I know that, this problem can be solved if i redirect my page to some other page,but i don't want to redirect my page,because after submitting data,an success message will show in that page.so how can i clear my form without redirecting my page?

this is my views.py file

```
def UserImageUpload(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your Image upload is waiting for Admin approval')


                    newdoc = Photo(photo = request.FILES['photo'],watermarked_image=request.FILES['photo'],user = request.user,name = request.POST['name'],description = request.POST['description'],keyword = request.POST['Image_Keyword'],uploaded_time=datetime.datetime.now(),Certified=request.POST['Certification'])

                    newdoc.save()
            else:
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Please Complete All Fields To Submit Your Image')



    else:
            form = DocumentForm()

    uploaded_image = Photo.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('myprofile/user_image_upload.html',{'uploaded_image':uploaded_image,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and this is my forms.py file

```
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    photo = forms.ImageField( 
            label='Select A file',)
    name = forms.CharField(label='Image Name',max_length=50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control',}))
    Certification = forms.BooleanField(label='I certify that this is my original work and I am atlest 18 years of age')
    description = forms.CharField(label='Image Description',max_length=500,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control',}))
    Image_Keyword = forms.CharField(label='Keywords',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control',}))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the views.py, After saving form just assign the empty form , like that

```
def UserImageUpload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
             form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
             if form.is_valid():
                     messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Your Image upload is waiting for Admin approval')
                     newdoc = Photo(photo = request.FILES['photo'],watermarked_image=request.FILES['photo'],user = request.user,name = request.POST['name'],description = request.POST['description'],keyword = request.POST['Image_Keyword'],uploaded_time=datetime.datetime.now(),Certified=request.POST['Certification'])
                     newdoc.save()
                #Assign the empty form,it will empty the form after a successful form submission
                     form=DocumentForm()  
             else:
                   messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Please Complete All Fields To Submit Your Image')
     else:
             form = DocumentForm()
     uploaded_image = Photo.objects.all()
     return render_to_response('myprofile/user_image_upload.html',{'uploaded_image':uploaded_image,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**no need to Redirect Your page.**

Answer (score 4):

While Rego's answer is technically correct, Django best practices dictate that you do a HttpResponseRedirect after a form submission.  This reduces the likelihood of accidental multiple submissions.

You have two options for sending data to the redirected page: you could either redirect to a page that indicates the form was submitted successfully, and/or you can use session variables.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/

Since you can't send your view's local variables to a view that you redirect to, you can save that data in session variables that will be available to any subsequent sessions until it expires or is deleted.

For instance, you could put the user's name in a session variable in one view:

```
# view.py (the one with the form)

request.session['name'] = form.cleaned_data['name']
```

And then in the view that processes your success notice:

```
# view.py (form submission successful)

string = "Hi there, " + request.session['name'] + "!  How are you today?"
```

This is preferable to not doing a redirect as strongly suggested by the Django gods.

Comment: You should use Django's messages framework to do this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60014682/

Answer (score 1):

It is **strongly advised** to do a redirect after a form submission to prevent accidental duplicate submissions (see [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).

You can use Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/) to show messages after the redirect. In your view:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
# ...

def UserImageUpload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # ... (do something with the submitted form data here) ...
            # The message that will be shown on subsequent displays of the template:
            messages.add_message(request,
                                 messages.SUCCESS,
                                 'Your Image upload is waiting for Admin approval')
            # Redirect back to this view.
            # Attention: Change '...' to the name or URL of this view.
            return redirect('...')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()

    return render(request, 'myprofile/user_image_upload.html', {
        'form': form,
        'uploaded_image': Photo.objects.all(),
    })
```

Then, you need to adjust your template (i.e. `myprofile/user_image_upload.html`) to be able to show the message during the next rendering of the template. Add something like this to your template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Read the [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages) for more details about displaying messages in your template.